# How to instantiate and use hardware/interfaces/audio/common/7.0/example service?

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to stub out audio HAL, and found this reference from Google:

"**example** — example implementation of the core and effect V7.0 API. It represents a “fake” audio HAL that doesn't actually communicate with hardware."
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/interfaces/+/refs/heads/master/audio/common/7.0/example/

I tried including the package:

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
    android.hardware.audio@7.0-service.example
```

Weird thing, I have to define HIDL on both `device/<product>/manifest.xml` and `common/7.0/example/android.hardware.audio@7.0-service.example.xml`.

If I remove the define from either side, the service will not register and it kept going to default `"android.hardware.audio@4/5/6/7/default"`.

But when I do have both XML defined, then I see this weird error:

```
01-01 00:01:17.235   151   151 E hwservicemanager: getDeviceHalManifest: -2147483648 VINTF parse error: 
Cannot add manifest fragment /vendor/etc/vintf/manifest/android.hardware.audio@7.0-service.example.xml: HAL "android.hardware.audio" has a conflict: 
Conflicting major version: 7.0 (from /vendor/etc/vintf/manifest.xml) vs. 7.0 (from /vendor/etc/vintf/manifest/android.hardware.audio@7.0-service.example.xml). 
Check whether or not multiple modules providing the same HAL are installed.
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this, in case others came to here later.

So, in terms of vent xml manifest, be sure to only have one definition only - either in your device/manifest.xml or use one provided by the package.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/interfaces/+/refs/heads/master/audio/common/7.0/example/android.hardware.audio%407.0-service.example.xml

Second, edit this *.rc file and change 'vendor.audio-hal-7-0' to 'vendor.audio-hal' as that is the service name other services will be referring to and not '-7-0' or any number specific.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/interfaces/+/refs/heads/master/audio/common/7.0/example/android.hardware.audio%407.0-service.example.rc